# Memory Error when training large dataset on tfidf

Tags: python, tf-idf

I am trying to train a large dataset containing 700000 rows containing 210+ million words. i have 8 gb memory . when i try to train it through tfidf it is giving me memory error. can someone guide me what exactly i am doing wrong
here is my sample training code

> self.vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.001, max_df=0.2, norm='l2', analyzer='word')
>
> ```
>     self.dim = None
>
> def learn(self, all_clean_text):      
>
>     print('Train feature extractor')
>     x = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(all_clean_text).toarray()
>
>     print (x.shape)
>     self.dim = x.shape[1]
>     print (self.dim)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Memory error means all this data cannot fit in your ram. 700k x 210m is 147,000 billions, so naturally, it's too large. You can start by deleting stop words, which could reduce the number of words drastically. Additionally, you can make sure you're using Python 64-bit. You could also use `max_df`, `min_df`, and `max_features`, but I'm not sure that would help.

Comment: Its actually not 700000*210 million. Each row consists of average 300 words so its total 210 million words. Can you guide me how much min and max df will be suitable